# Connect device to local host Server

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, autobahn

I'm integrating Autobahn into my android application.  I have created a basic node.js server which I have added a json object to.  The ip/port combo is 127.0.0.1:8124.

I am trying to connect to this via web sockets by integrating Autobahn from an android device.

The error returned is:

```
Connection Lost Reason: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8124) after 6000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

My code to run autobahn is:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {

private WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout, null);
        start();
        return view;
}

  private void start(){
        final String wsuri = "ws://127.0.0.1:8124";

        try{
            mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onOpen(){
                    Log.d(m_TAG, "Status connected to: " +wsuri);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(String payload){
                    Log.d(m_TAG, "Got echo: "+ payload);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason){
                    Log.d(m_TAG, "Connection Lost " + "Reason: " + reason);
                }
            });
        }catch (WebSocketException e){
            Log.d(m_TAG, e.toString());
      }
    }
}
```

I know that there is an issue with connecting to the local ip rather than the global ip but I'm unsure how to fix this....

**EDIT** 
Just to note, I have tried this from my emulator using 10.0.2.2 but it I still get the same error.  If anyone could help with this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: are you trying to connect to your pc from your device? Do you have a emulator on your pc running? Where is the node.js server?

Comment: I run the node.js on my machine, there is no emulator running on it.  So I am trying to connect my android device to the server on my machine...

Comment: ok, so just try to figure out which ip your local machine has in your LAN (ipconfig / ifconfig) and close all firewalls. 127.0.0.1 is always the device itself. So when you are trying to connect from 127.0.0.1 (aka localhost) from your android it tries to connect to itself.

Comment: ok, sorry for my confusion but, the address for my server is 127.0.0.1:8124, if I put that in my browser it displays test data.  so in order for me to connect to that server from an external device, what is it I need to do?  I've ran ifconfig it lists  127.0.0.1 - then inet: 192.168.0.*** - broadcast 192.168.0.***  both the inet and broadcast are different

Comment: also i have tried connecting to the local ip of the machine 192.168.0.102:8124 but I still get a connection error

Comment: Yeah try it with 192.168.0.****. 127.0.0.1 is you local machine, so it is understandable that from your browser it works (from your machine) But from the device you need the LAN Ip which is 192.168.0.**** But make sure your android device is connected to the same router as your pc!

Comment: http://www.qnapsecurity.com/images/products/Application/NVR101/app17.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70698/discussion-between-a-s-and-dj-doo).